# How to add json_encode array into json_encode object?

Tags: php, arrays, json

How to add json_encode array into json_encode object ? or other way to make below result?

php result response to jquery ajax

```
{”a_obj”:”a_obj”,“b_obj_json”:[
        {“b_arr1”:b_arr1,“b_arr1-2”:“b_arr1-2”},
        {“b_arr2”:b_arr2,“b_arr2-2”:”b_arr2-2”},
        ... from db push
    ]
}
```

:

```
$response_array = array('a_array'=>'a_array');
$response_array_object = json_encode($response_array, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);


$b_arr =array(
     'b_arr1'=>'b_arr1',
);
json_encode($b_arr);

$response_array_object->append($b_arr);

echo $response_array_object;
```

Comment: Convert JSON to Array with 'json_decode' then use 'array_append' to add new data then 'json_encode' it again.

Comment: JSON is just a string. You can't manipulate it as a data structure anymore. Build your PHP array structures as you need them, *then* JSON encode the whole thing.

Comment: can you show me some example correct php array, because after I use json_encode the array will not left json array all become object

Answer (score 0):

Convert JSON to Array with 'json_decode' 
then use 'array_append' to add new data then 'json_encode' it again.

```
<?php
$json = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';
$array = (array) json_decode($json);

$append = array(
    'username' => array('alias' => 'somename', 'realname' => 'stacky');
    'password' => 'somepass';
);

$combined = array_merge($array, $append);
$encoded = json_encode($combined);

print_r($encoded);
?>
```